# Qt/QML: How to refer to a component/object from a GridView's model's ListElement

Tags: qt, components, qml

I have a `GridView` with a delegate that is supposed to use a `Loader` to load and display components which are defined in the same QML file.

Let's say I have a GridView like this:

```
GridView {
    delegate: Rectangle {
        Loader { sourceComponent: model.pageContents }
    }
    model: ListModel {
        ListElement { /* how do I reference any of the components defined below from here, so the Loader can actually load and display it...  ? */ }
    }
}



Component {
    id: page_01
    Rectangle { 
        color: "red"
        // Page contents for page 1 go here.
    }
}



Component {
    id: page_02
    Rectangle { 
        color: "red"
        // Page contents for page 2 go here.
    }
}
```

I know I can create QML objects and components from Strings, external files and URLs. But I'd like to ideally do something like this:

```
ListModel {
    ListElement { pageContents: page_01 }
    ListElement { pageContents: page_02 }
}
```

I'd prefer to keep everything in a single QML file, so I can easily transfer and store it on the device without having to worry about resolving external dependencies, etc.

How do I refer to components in the same QML file from within `ListElement`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to `ListElement` values limitation you cannot just put item `id` here. But you easily can use some external storage, for example property to store pointers to your pages. In example below I use array with pages `id`s and an index to wanted page as `ListElement` data:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600

    GridView {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        property var pages: [page_01, page_02]
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement { pageIndex: 0 }
            ListElement { pageIndex: 1 }
        }

        delegate: Loader { sourceComponent: grid.pages[pageIndex] }
    }

    Component {
        id: page_01
        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
            width: 100
            height: 100
            Component.onCompleted: console.log("page_01 was created")
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: page_02
        Rectangle {
            color: "blue"
            width: 100
            height: 100
            Component.onCompleted: console.log("page_02 was created")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks really clever. I'll try it out and report back!